# Android Studio design tokens

Tags: android, user-interface, design-tokens

There are JSON with colors how to convert it to XML file

Context:
Figma has colors (design tokens) that have been converted to JSON and we want to import them into Android Studio

Comment: Please provide some additional details, esp. code, to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show your JSON files and instruction that you've done.